# Randomness of a linear congruential genarator in jumbling values of an array

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, random, algorithmic-randomness

I am working on a school project and it requires a simple pseudo-random number generating algorithm. I thought of using a linear congruential generator for this purpose.

This came to my mind as  it is easy to understand and to compute.

I known that LCGs are not random enough and recur too soon.
But I will be using only the part before the recurrence, in order to jumble the values of an array. So what random properties can I expect in my jumbled list. Is it good enough to give a fairly bizarre sequence of numbers, or is the jumbling pretty simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a Linear Congruential Generator works pretty well if any values have to be jumbled. But it is best if it is not used if its for somthing that requires more randomness, like cryptography.